# Which is asymptotically larger $n \log(n)$ or $n$ analytically?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Which is asymptotically larger $n \log(n)$ or $n$ analytically? If we take the ratio we get $\log(n)$ and if we set $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(n)$ the value of the limit is $\infty$. Then how can we tell which is asymptotically larger?

$n \log(n)$ is intuitively asymptotically larger than $n$. But how can it be proved analytically?

Comment: what is your definition for "asymptotically larger" ?

Comment: Of course as $n$ increases for substantial values of $n$, the value of $ n\log(n)$ blows up as compared to $n$. But how can it be proved with limits since the definition involves the  $\lim_{n\to\infty} $ not equals to $\infty$

Comment: which definition ? prove what ? and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = +\infty$ has a different meaning from "$f(n)$ is a divergent sequence" : it means $f(n)$ is divergent AND its values are greater and greater, or equivalently, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{f(n)} = 0^+$ thing that you wouldn't have  known simply with "$f(n)$ is a non convergent (divergent) sequence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig into the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, you can see that it means for all $M$, there exists $x_M$ such that $f(x)\ge M$ for $x\ge x_M$.

In terms of comparing $n$ and $n\log n$, we can apply this reasoning to get some fairly explicit bounds. Let $M$ be some (large, if you'd like) positive number - then, whenever $n\ge e^M$, we have that $\log n \ge M$, and thus that $n\log n \ge Mn$.

So, for any $M>0$, $n\log n \ge Mn$ eventually. Hopefully this goes some way to justifying that $n\log n$ dominates $n$ by some margin.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide two equatipns you get $log(n)$ in numerator. Now for big values of n ofcourse $log(n)>1$ thus its proved. Also for small $n$ the equation $log(n)\approx n$ so $nlog(n)$ becomes $\approx n^2$ while it is easily observed that $nlog(n)>n$ for big values or you can also sketch their graphs place and you will get relation as $nlog(n)>=n$